# I get an illegal reference and a type name not allowed, why?

Tags: c++

I have come futher in my project but alas im stuck again.
I've got the game loop running from 1 class now.

I'm trying to get the player variables to update in the player class upon a key press(see line 57 to 68 in game.cpp).

These variables are saved in private variables and then pushed into public referneces.
Then the game loop should update the players position with the Fill() function in the game loop.

The errors im getting go as these:

C2597 illegal refernce to non-static member 'Player::positionX' game.cpp line 55

C2597 illegal refernce to non-static member 'Player::positionX' game.cpp line 55

E0254 type name is not allowed, game.cpp line 30

E0254 type name is not allowed, game.cpp line 30

```
// Game.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "olcConsoleGameEngine.h"
#include "Player.h"



using namespace std;




class GameFunction : public olcConsoleGameEngine{
public:
    GameFunction() {
    }


protected:
    bool OnUserCreate() override {
        return true;

    }

    bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) override {
        Fill(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), L' ');

        Fill(Player.RplayerPositionX, 5 * 29, Player.RplayerPositionY, 5 * 29 + 10, PIXEL_SOLID, 5);


        return true;

    }

};


int main()
{



    string name = "stirng";
    
    int var = 0;

    GameFunction game;
    Player player(100, 70, 80);


    game.ConstructConsole(160, 160, 8, 8);
    game.Start();

    //player movement
    switch (cin.get()) {
    case 'a':
        player.playerPositionLeft(10);
        break;
    case 'd':
        player.playerPositionRight(10);
        break;

    default:
        return 0;
        break;
    }


    return 0;
}

// Run program: Ctrl + F5 or Debug > Start Without Debugging menu
// Debug program: F5 or Debug > Start Debugging menu

// Tips for Getting Started: 
//   1. Use the Solution Explorer window to add/manage files
//   2. Use the Team Explorer window to connect to source control
//   3. Use the Output window to see build output and other messages
//   4. Use the Error List window to view errors
//   5. Go to Project > Add New Item to create new code files, or Project > Add Existing Item to add existing code files to the project
//   6. In the future, to open this project again, go to File > Open > Project and select the .sln file
```

```
#pragma once

class Player{
public:
    //constructor
    inline Player(int health, int positionX, int positionY) {
        playerHealth = health;
        playerPositionX = positionX;
        playerPositionY = positionY;

    }
    
    int& RplayerHealth = playerHealth;
    int& RplayerPositionX = playerPositionX;
    int& RplayerPositionY = playerPositionY;


private:
    //player variables
    int playerHealth;
    int playerPositionX;
    int playerPositionY;

public:
    //player functions
    void playerPositionLeft(int num) {
        playerPositionX += num;
        playerPositionY -= num;

    }

    void playerPositionRight(int num) {
        playerPositionY += num;
        playerPositionX -= num;

    }



};
```

i was also able to cut down on files and amount of code, any help is appreciated, cuz then i finally have a moving character!

github: https://github.com/JarodIking/Game-C-

Comment: Public references to private variables means that you in effect have public variables, and a handful of unexpected problems to go with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `GameFunction` a reference to the player and let it store it:

```
// Inside the GameFunction class
GameFunction(Player& player) : p(player) {}

Player& p;
```

Then you can access members of `p` inside `OnUserUpdate`:

```
bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) override {
    Fill(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), L' ');
    Fill(p.playerPositionX, 5 * 29, p.playerPositionY, 5 * 29 + 10, PIXEL_SOLID, 5);
    return true;
}
```

Note that the code as is will not compile because `playerPositionX` is `private`. Either make it `public` or add getter methods and use those.

Comment: Is there anything i need to add to the initialization at line 48 in game.cpp, i get a E0153, expression needs class type, i try doing this: GameFunction game(Player player); . do you have a better solution?

Comment: When calling a function or initializing a variable via a constructor, you need to pass expressions, not declarations. try `GameFunction game(player);` instead.

Comment: ah yes that solved it, also needed to define player, just one more error, C2228 left of '.constructConsole' must have class/struct/ union

Comment: without knowing anything about your code i'll guess that the compiler does not have the full declaration of GameFunction in scope , or it is not declared yet at that point.